# Return first numeric value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

This is pretty much what my dataframe looks like (indexed by `year` and `countries`.)

```
                   ISO   gini  efw
year    countries                                                                                   
1970    Argentina   ARG  NaN   5.67 
1975    Argentina   ARG  NaN   3.13
1980    Argentina   ARG  40.8  4.25
1985    Argentina   ARG  NaN   3.53
1990    Argentina   ARG  NaN   4.47 
1970    Bolivia     BOL  NaN   NaN  
1975    Bolivia     BOL  NaN   NaN
1980    Bolivia     BOL  NaN   4.08
1985    Bolivia     BOL  NaN   3.52 
1990    Bolivia     BOL  42.0  5.62 
2010    Uruguay     URY  44.5  7.33
2011    Uruguay     URY  42.2  7.39
2012    Uruguay     URY  39.9  7.34
2013    Uruguay     URY  40.5  7.26 
1970    Venezuela   VEN  NaN   7.18
1975    Venezuela   VEN  NaN   6.22
1980    Venezuela   VEN  NaN   6.72 
1985    Venezuela   VEN  NaN   6.08
1990    Venezuela   VEN  NaN   5.55
1995    Venezuela   VEN  47.8  4.35
2000    Venezuela   VEN  NaN   5.89
```

I want to come up with a function that identifies the first non `NaN` value in the `gini` column, and returns the `year` and `efw` value that correspond to the value in the `gini` column.

For example, if the first non `Nan` for `Argentina` is 40.8, I want the function to return 40.8, the year for that value (1980), and the value for `efw` also for 1980 (4.25).

Ideally the new dataframe would look like this. That for every country.

```
                    ISO   gini  efw
year    countries                                                                                   
1980    Argentina   ARG  40.8   4.25 
2016    Argentina   ARG  43.60  3.13
```

The last row corresponds to 2016, the last year for which there is data available.

Comment: Can you check your desired output df there? I don't see where you got the second row from... First makes sense, second I don't see here. Wouldn't the next row be `1990 Bolivia BOL 32.0 5.62`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why `year` and `countries` are indexes? I recommend those to be columns as those are more flexible to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, get by condition, then reset the index, then sort the values, then multiindex the dataframe again:

```
print(df[df['gini'].notnull()].reset_index().sort_values('year').iloc[[0, -1]].set_index(['year','countries']))
```